# double and float memory allocation on modern comptuers

Tags: c++

I am learning about double and float and what the difference is. I ran a piece of code as posted below, to see how much memory is allocated depending on how many integers I add and decimal points but it seems that no matter how many integers I type I always get size 8 bytes for both float and double. I learned that float occupies 4 bytes, but Im starting to think that on modern computers that's not the case and perhaps this was the case back in the days and today we can use them interchangeably without affecting the results? Am I missing something here?

```
   // C++ program to sizes of data types
  #include<iostream>
  using namespace std;

  int main()
  {

cout << "Size of int : " << sizeof(11111111111111111) << " bytes" << endl;

cout << "Size of float : " << sizeof(11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111) << " bytes" <<endl;
cout << "Size of double : " << sizeof(.11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111) << " bytes" << endl;


  return 0;
 }
```

Comment: `cout << "Size of float : " << sizeof(11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111) << " bytes" <<endl;` - this is not printing `sizeof` a `float` it's printing `sizeof` a `double`. If you want a `float` then do `cout << "Size of float : " << sizeof(11111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111.1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111111f) << " bytes" <<endl;` - note the `f` postfix.

Comment: Why not use something like `sizeof((float)1)` to minimize cross-problems..?

Comment: Ok, I tried it, it now reads 4 bytes. What's the diference? Why do I need an f at the end? and was the compiler converting the float to double?

Comment: It wasn't "converting" a float: there never was a float in that case.

Comment: By default a floating point literal is a `double`. If you want a `float` literal you need to say so by adding the `f` postfix.

Comment: I see, I had a double in there. That makes sense Jesper! I wasnt aware I needed the f. Thank you

Comment: Also, the type of your first literal `11111111111111111` is not `int`, it's `long`.  It's at least 32 bits wide, hence the result of 8 bytes there too.

Answer (score 3):

You print the size of `double` on both lines, because both floating point literals has the type of `double`. If you want to create a `float` literal, append an `f` to it: `1.0f`. This has the type of `float`. If you don't append an `f` to it, it will have the type of `double`.

Or you can just simply use `sizeof(float)`.